# Can we use rnfirebase in expo-cli

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Hey this is saksham can someone pls tell me can we use rnfirebase (https://rnfirebase.io/) in my expo-cli (https://expo.dev/) projects

Answer (score 1):

In its [managed workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow) [Expo uses the JavaScript SDKs](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) to access Firebase, and you can't replace those with React Native Firebase (which wraps Firebase's native SDKs for iOS and Android).

In a [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) of Expo, you can use any package you want, including `react-native-firebase`. See the documentation on [bare workflow setup](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) for more, specifically the (short) section on [Usage with react-native-firebase](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/guides/setup-native-firebase.md#usage-with-react-native-firebase).

This article [How to integrate react-native-firebase with Expo](https://bartlomiej-klocek.medium.com/how-to-integrate-react-native-firebase-into-expo-d34712eaf64d) also looks promising, although admittedly I just found that by searching for [react-native-firebase in expo](https://www.google.com/search?q=react-native-firebase+in+expo).